# Looking for a best practice to filter module output in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, filter, module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

A client of me is migrating to a new CMS and the old CMS contains placeholders in the content that need to be replaced, something like (bad example ahead): `{{ID:CurrentShoppingId}}`, which would be replaced with the ID of the current shopper.

I can think of three ways, but I'm totally open to new and better suggestions:

- Create a new module based on HTML Module. Drawbacks: a module cannot be inherited from, so we have to use the source and alter it, or create a module from scratch;
- Find out whether there's an event like `OnParseHtmlContent` and register a delegate;
- Use the good old (bad) approach of filtering the output response stream.

As far as I know, there's no built-in method in DNN to do this (as opposed to — say — WordPress, where filter upon filter is built).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML modules supports limited [token replacement](http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/DNNTextHTMLTokenReplacementOptions/tabid/866/language/en-US/Default.aspx). For something more robust there are third party modules available as well. http://www.avatar-soft.ro/dotnetnuke/modules/token-replacement/my-tokens.aspx

Comment: Just what I need. Thanks. I also read that it is possible to create your own token-replacement classes, correct?

Comment: I am not sure. You may also want to look at PageBlaster, it is a popular module and has a "Powerful Replacement Engine" http://www.snapsis.com/DotNetNuke-Performance-Caching-Compression-Optimization.aspx